# skip starting from a character in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

> :v3.11.3-4.38

and I want to get `:v3.11.3` (and skip `-4.38`) in a variable named `version`.

I am trying this but not helping:

```
^.*:(v?)(?P<version>.*(?:-.*)$)
```

Is it possible to skip a hyphen (or any specific character) and the following characters in *capturing group*?

Comment: Try `^.*(?P<version>:v?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/Sf2a3O/1

Comment: You can use `version = re.sub(r'-.*$', '', value)`

Comment: Hi @kmar, what do you want get? Do you have only this paricular string as a source or meny strings with this pattern: `^.*:v\d\.\d\d.\d-\d\.\d\d.*$:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to get the version that is the last match on a line meeting the `:v?<version-number>` pattern.

You may use

```
^.*:v?(?P<version>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
```

Move the `(` parenthesis to adjust the start of the named group if necessary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzCtLB/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0 or more characters other than line break chars as many as possible
- `:v?` - `:` or `:v`
- `(?P<version>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` - Named capturing group `version`: 1+ digits and then 0 or more sequences of `.` and 1+ digits.

Comment: you example is working - but i bit confused - you are using \.\d+ as part of non-capturing group - but it still take capture those values too - PS: if I remove ?: in you regex it still works.

Comment: @kumar Non-capturing group patterns still *consume* text, you can't expect regex engine to skip parts of matches in the middle. If you use `re.findall` with a `^.*:v?(?P<version>\d+(\.\d+)*)`, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the pattern for the part you want to exclude outside of the capturing group, like this:

```
^.*:(v?)(?P<version>[^-]*)(?:-.*)$
```

Since there's a catch-all `.*` after the version number as well, I've excluded the `-` from that so that it will only match the string up until the `-`.

Comment: Hi @Rob thanks! your example works if input is :v3.11.3-4.38. But there is case where the input is :v3.11.3 (and I expect :v3.11.3 as output) and it is not working. Any help here?

Comment: Ah, if that's a possibility, then you can put a `?` after that last group like so `^.*:(v?)(?P<version>[^-]*)(?:-.*)?$`. That will make it optional, but also make sure you can't have any other characters between the version number and the end of the string. If you don't care about the format of the rest of the string after the version number, then you can remove the last part of the regex entirely, i.e. `^.*:(v?)(?P<version>[^-]*)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only need such a **simple expression**: `(:v\d\.\d\d\.\d)`

**You can use it like that:**

```
>>> import re
>>> line = ':v3.11.3-4.38'
>>> searchObj = re.search( r'(:v\d\.\d\d\.\d)', line)
>>> version = searchObj.group(1)
>>> version
':v3.11.3'
```

This works for both *Python 2* and *Python 3*.

> Is it possible to skip a hyphen (or any specific character) and the following characters in capturing group?

No you have to use two separate groups to achieve this.